# Unable to style ul nested within another ul

Tags: html, css

Despite it being a simple issue, I am unable to understand why I am unable to style the nested ul.

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">select1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-left ul ul li {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Any ideas anyone?
Thank you all in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: you are setting white (#fff) color for the border, I think you noticed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually everything works there.

Here is your code with a change of colors:

```css
.footer-left ul ul li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">select1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Note that if you want the `<a>` elements to have different color you will need to color them separately:

```css
.footer-left ul ul li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: red;
  background: black;
}

.footer-left ul ul li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">select1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for border.
    .footer-left ul li ul li{}

and for href color
    .footer-left ul li ul li a{}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the link colors to be white (#fff), try below css:

```
.footer-left ul ul li {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.footer-left ul ul li a:link {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class for it will not confusion to chaining selector

```css
.footer-left ul.child>li {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background:#ddd;
}
.footer-left ul.child>li>a {
 color:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li>
      <ul class="child">
        <li><a href="#">select1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">select3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```